# Extend SqlException and add a property to it

Tags: c#, oop, static, sqlexception

I'm trying to extend `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` and add a property to it. So that, on every `SqlCommand` execution, if an exception is thrown, I can capture it, add the SQL that was executed, and re-throw it.

I have done extensions before, but only with methods. With properties I can't manage it to work.

```
public static class SqlExceptionExtention{
    public static string query { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried all combinations of adding and removing the static flag, and nothing works. Of course the property can't be static, it must be specific to each object.

Comment: You can only add extension methods, not properties or fields. You can subclass it, catch the `SqlException` and then rethrow your new exception with the sql attached.

Comment: You don't need an extension. You have to extend `SqlException` by creating a custom class that inherits from it.. **Edit** `SqlException` is sealed, you can't do that. You could extend `DbException` with a class that takes a `SqlException` as constructor parameter, the query and a meaningful message. You could name it `SqlQueryExecutionException`

Comment: C# does not support extension properties -- although [proposals have been discussed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/112). You are free to implement a `GetQuery()` extension method, but tracking instance data through extension methods is finicky and complicated. Since `SqlException` is `sealed`, you can't extend it either. Consider introducing a wrapper class and keeping the `SqlException` as the `InnerException` of that -- or, per Sean's answer, use the `Data` property every exception has (nice catch, pardon the pun).

Comment: @TimSchmelter `SqlException` is sealed :-(

Comment: @Sean: already edited my comment ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as extension properties, only extension methods.

If you want to add data then you could use the [Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data(v=vs.110).aspx) property to populate the dictionary:

```
try
{
  // Do something
}
catch(SqlException e)
{
  e.Data.Add("Foo", "Bar");
  throw;
}
```